# Где лучше(правильно) сделать проверку на правильность вводимых данных?

Tags: java, hibernate

В сеттерах описания таблиц:

```
public void setSchemaName(SchemaName schemaName) {
    this.schemaName = schemaName;
}

public void setProductBrand(ProductBrand productBrand) {
    this.productBrand = productBrand;
}

public void setHydrantWithout(Integer hydrantWithout) {
    this.hydrantWithout = hydrantWithout;
}

public void setHydrantFrom(Integer hydrantFrom) {
    this.hydrantFrom = hydrantFrom;
```

Или перед тем, где буду использовать DAO:

```
if(result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){

    //тут обновление в таблице БД(вот тут будет вызов DAO)<-------
    //если удачно - обновляем данные в таблице программы

    List<String> newRow = modalPanel.getValue();
    newRow.add(0, id);
    getTblPanel().setValueRow(index, newRow);
}
```

Просто везде где смотрел, предполагается создание ещё одного слоя(зачем???), где будут проверки и открытия сессии и от куда уже будут юзаться методы DAO.

P.S. Пример метода:

```
@Override
public void create(ProductType object) {

    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(object);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {

        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Ошибка", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    } finally {

        if (session != null)
            session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: а какая архитектура у вашего приложения? это настольное приложение?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да, это настольное приложение.

Comment: а арихитектура какая?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman э, это как? В смысле?
Хибернейт + я художник, я так вижу.

Comment: знаете про трехслойную архитектуру? про MVC/MVP/MV*?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, но как этим пользоваться - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) и описать ограничения (constraints) данных в ваших моделях.

Проверку правильности данных вы можете делать в двух местах:

- в контроллере / в слое бизнес-логики
- в моделе / в слое данных

В первом случае можно проверять данные по мере их ввода пользователем, а во втором в момент сохранения в базу данных. Какой выбрать зависит от данных и от интерфейса взаимодействия с пользователем.

Comment: Ага, спасибо большое)

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что нужно проверять и в самой базе данных. Путем введения различных constraints (not null, unique, foreign keys ... etc).

Comment: @Damintsew это очень сильно зависит от проекта. Иногда это может больно ударить в будущем.

Comment: Я не могу придумать такую ситуацию... @MikhailVaysman, можете привести пример ?

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение в предыдущему ответу я хочу добавить, что валидировать данные можно и нужно на уровне самой базы данных. Осуществить это можно с помощью различных ограничений (constraints). Таких как:

- not null
- unique
- foreign keys

Введение этих условий позволит избежать ошибок, когда данные создаются руками. Также избавит от ошибок (багов) в программе при создании/модификации/удалении сущностей.

**Пример**

Довольно рафинированный, но надеюсь он Вам поможет. У нас есть две **логически** связанные сущности `Person`, `Event`. При этом у `Person` нет ссылки на `Event`, а у `Event` есть ссылка.

Тогда без foreign key `Event -> Person`. Мы можем удалить `Person` и у нас "повиснут в воздухе" сущности `Event`, которые ни к какому человеку не относятся. И таким образом могут поучиться битые данные.

В случае наличия foreign key, **сама база** запретит удалять `Person` (у нас будет Exception при коммите транзакции).